# Closed form expression of the nth term

Tags: recurrence-relations

> We have to find the closed form of the nth term of the recurrence relation:$$a_n = 2 a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$$ $\forall n > 1$ It is given that $a_0 = 0, a_1 = 1$

---

I got the characteristics equation to be $x^2-2x-1=0$ and it has $2$ roots $1\pm √2$. But do I get a closed form expression of $a_n$ from this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Closed form solution of recurrence relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58502/closed-form-solution-of-recurrence-relation)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find its closed-form?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254697/how-to-find-its-closed-form) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a_n%3D2a_%7Bn-1%7D%2Ba_%7Bn-2%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aclosed%20form&p=1). This has somewhat different initial conditions, but the approach is otherwise basically the same. Also, note there are quite a few other duplicates, as well as very similar questions, e.g., [Finding a closed form formula for a recursive sequence.](/q/2459921), ...

Comment: (cont.) [Is the recurrence relation a good way to compute $x_n$ from arbitrary initial values $x_0$ and $x_1$?](/q/2422824), [How can I find a functional closed expression for this sequence for the nth term?](/q/3818785), etc. Last, but not least, welcome to Math SE.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a nice rule that states that if the roots to the characteristic equation are $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then $$a_n=A\alpha^n+B\beta^n$$ is the closed form expression to the sequence. So in your case, $\alpha=1+\sqrt2$ and $\beta=1-\sqrt2$. All it remains is to substitute the values we were given to find $A$ and $B$.
$$a_0=0=A(1+\sqrt2)^0+B(1-\sqrt2)^0$$ $$\implies 0=A+B$$
and
$$a_1=1=A(1+\sqrt2)^1+B(1-\sqrt2)^1$$
$$\implies1=A+B+\sqrt2A-\sqrt2B$$
$$\implies1=\sqrt2A-\sqrt2B$$

Solving the two simultaneous equations for $A$, $B$ we have
$$A=\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}$$
$$B=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}$$

in other words, substituting these values of $A$ and $B$ back we have
$$a_n=\frac{(1+\sqrt2)^n}{2\sqrt2}-\frac{(1-\sqrt2)^n}{2\sqrt2}$$
which is the closed form expression for this sequence. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can write
$$\left( \begin{matrix}
   {{a}_{n+1}}  \\
   {{a}_{n}}  \\
\end{matrix} \right)=\left( \begin{matrix}
   2 & 1  \\
   1 & 0  \\
\end{matrix} \right)\left( \begin{matrix}
   {{a}_{n}}  \\
   {{a}_{n-1}}  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$$

The eigenvalues of this matrix M are the roots of your characteristic equation. The matrix can be diagonalized in the form $M = UDU^{-1}$ where D is diagonal with entries the 2 eigenvalues and U has columns which are the corresponding eigenvectors. Then $M^n = UD^nU^{-1}$ and

$$\left( \begin{matrix}
   {{a}_{n+1}}  \\
   {{a}_{n}}  \\
\end{matrix} \right)=UD^nU^{-1}
\left( \begin{matrix}
   {{a}_{1}}  \\
   {{a}_{0}}  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$$

from which $a_n$ can be read off.